# How to uncheck all radio buttons in a radio group, when a radio button is checked in Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I have created programmatically 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. The problem is, when i first check a radio button from the first radio group and after that i check the second radio button from the same radio group, the first radio button remains checked. What can i do to have the normal behavior for all the radio buttons in the radio group?
This is my code:

```
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Checking one `RadioButton` that belongs to a `RadioGroup` unchecks any previously checked `RadioButton` within the same group." Source: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

If I understand right: You are talking about 4 `RadioButtons` in the same `RadioGroup` that refuse to uncheck themselves when another button in the same `RadioGroup` gets checked?

If that's the case, just give a different `Resource ID` to every RadioButton and that should fix it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first radio button that i checked from the first radio group, remains checked. This is happening in each radio group. But for example in the second radio group, after i check 2 radio buttons, the second remains checked.
i set `radioGroup[i].setId(i);` and `answer[j].setId(j);` to have different id's but nothing changed. Any other idea?

Comment: Try to set the id like this `answer[j].setId(i + "_" + j);` , because if you have more than 1 radio group, the buttons inside them will have the same id.

Comment: Doesn't work. This is the error: `setId(int) in View cannot be applied to java.lang.string`. How can i do?

Comment: Oh because it needs an int, not a string. So you can do this: `answer[j].setId(Integer.parseInt(i + "" + j));`

Comment: It give's me another error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0_0"`. But i figured out: `answer[j].setId(j+100);` and works!
Thank you!

Comment: It was my fault in the beginning because I wrote "_" between i and j but you can simply remove that underscore and make it a unique id by using the latest edit of my last comment